# C# Script - Adding Custom Class

Tags: c#, execution, .net-assembly

I'm making a script system and i need some help.
I've my class named `Script.cs` and my class named `Person.cs`.

The `Person.cs` is set at the first program run (and can be set again during the execution). I want to get the `Person.cs` Methods to use on my script, look it:

**Person.cs**

```
//constructors

public string getName() { return m_name; }
public string getAge() { return m_age; }
```

**Main.cs**

```
//constructors
Person ps;
public void Run()
{
    ps = new Person("name", "10");
}
```

**Script.cs**

> How can i do to the Person can be "runned" on script execution...

Sorry if i didn't express myself well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what it is you're asking here. Can you edit your question to explain what "the `Person` can be "runned"" means? There's nothing in your posted code that I can see that explains what you're wanting to accomplish. Thanks. :)

Comment: Voting to close as very unclear question. At this point it looks like "how can I create scripting in C#" which is bigger than can be answered here and also well covered .

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to change `Run` to `Main`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3(v=vs.71).aspx.  Be sure to set your project to use your `Main` class as the entry point.

Also, it looks like `Name` and `Age` should be properties in `Person`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Comment: It is propertie on Person, but on my script, it's running realtime... I put the code on richTextBox and click on execute, i need when i digit getName() and click execute, it return the name declared on class...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn), which allows you to use C# as a scripting language. Here's a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113169/C-As-A-Scripting-Language-In-Your-NET-Applications) to get you started.